# Zipentry is not streaming files in order in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to stream files from a zip file using ZipEntry class in android, however I am not getting the files in alphabetical order.

Here is my code:

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);
     ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
     try {
         ZipEntry ze;
         while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
             ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
             int count;
             while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                 baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
             }
             String filename = ze.getName();
             byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
             int value = progress++;
                task.doProgress(value);
             Log.e(" -- zip process ---", "Filename: " + filename.toString());
             // do something with 'filename' and 'bytes'...
         }
     } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         Log.e("Database Install", "Error: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
         try {
            zis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the code.

Comment: What makes you think something will be in alphabetical order here?

Comment: It just seemed a logical outcome. When I open the zip file it shows the files in alphabetical order. Also, ZipFile class is designed for random access of files inside a zip file, so I assumed ZipEntry should stream files in order.

Comment: That order is likely arbitrary and the viewer you used just defaults to alphabetical order.  There is nowhere in the Android documentation for `ZipEntry`, `ZipInputStream` or `ZipOutputStream` that suggests there is any sort of ordering applied.

Comment: Then what is the best way to arrange the files in any order, alphabetical or otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ZipInputStream` reads entries sequentially so they can't be in alphabetical order in general. If you want them to be in alphabetical order you should read them first using `ZipFile.entries()`, sort as you like and access entries using `ZipFile.getEntry()`.

Comment: pity the entries() is not avaialble on ZipInputStream :-(